# Change IP - choosing LAN-Adapter (.net)

Tags: vb.net, network-programming, ip

i got at my pc (Windows 7 and 10) 3 active LAN-Adapters.

In history I used netsh, because you can choose an adapter

> netsh interface ip set address ""LAN-BRIDGED"" static 192.168.255.130 255.255.255.128 192.168.255.129", AppWinStyle.Hide, True)

But sometimes netsh doesn´t work... So thats why I don´t want to use netsh.

Now I try it by another way to change IP + Subnet + Gateway. If I only activate one of these LAN-Adapters, my code works. But if all of them active then it changes the IP at a random LAN-Adapter.

How can i choose one exactly LAN-Adapter with my code?

```
Option Strict On
Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation
Imports System.Management
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim LAN_Adapter As NetworkInterface
        ComboBoxAdapterSelector.Items.Clear()
        For Each LAN_Adapter In NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
            With LAN_Adapter
                ComboBoxAdapterSelector.Items.Add(.Name)
            End With
        Next
    End Sub
    Private Sub ChangechoosenIPButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ChangechoosenIPButton.Click
        ChangechoosenIP()
    End Sub
    Sub ChangechoosenIP()
        Dim IPAddress As String = TextBoxIPAddress.Text
        Dim SubnetMask As String = TextBoxSubnetMask.Text
        Dim Gateway As String = TextBoxGateway.Text
        If ComboBoxAdapterSelector.SelectedText = "Ethernet 2" Then
            Dim objMC As ManagementClass = New ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration")
            Dim objMOC As ManagementObjectCollection = objMC.GetInstances()
            For Each objMO As ManagementObject In objMOC
                Try
                    Dim objNewIP As ManagementBaseObject = Nothing
                    Dim objSetIP As ManagementBaseObject = Nothing
                    Dim objNewGate As ManagementBaseObject = Nothing
                    objNewIP = objMO.GetMethodParameters("EnableStatic")
                    objNewGate = objMO.GetMethodParameters("SetGateways")
                    objNewGate("DefaultIPGateway") = New String() {Gateway}
                    objNewGate("GatewayCostMetric") = New Integer() {1}
                    objNewIP("IPAddress") = New String() {IPAddress}
                    objNewIP("SubnetMask") = New String() {SubnetMask}
                    objSetIP = objMO.InvokeMethod("EnableStatic", objNewIP, Nothing)
                    objSetIP = objMO.InvokeMethod("SetGateways", objNewGate, Nothing)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show("Error : " & ex.Message)
                End Try
            Next objMO
        ElseIf ComboBoxAdapterSelector.SelectedText = "Ethernet" Then
            '.
            '.
            '.
        ElseIf ComboBoxAdapterSelector.SelectedText = "LAN-Connection" Then
            '.
            '.
            '.
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try this code on `(LAN and Wireless)`

```
For Each objMO As ManagementObject In objMOC
    If objMO.SystemProperties("MACAddress").Value IsNot Nothing Then

        '***** USE THIS  
        If objMO.SystemProperties("Description").Value <> "RAS Async Adapter" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Caption: " & objMO.SystemProperties("Caption").Value)
            'your code  
        End If


        '***** OR THIS 
        'If objMO.SystemProperties("IPEnabled").Value = True And objMO.SystemProperties("DefaultIPGateway").Value IsNot Nothing Then
        '    MessageBox.Show("Caption: " & objMO.SystemProperties("Caption").Value)
        '    'your code
        'End If

    End If
Next
```

Comment: where do you choose between LAN and Wireless in your code? Is one of your Adapter called "RAS Async Adapter"?

Comment: I mean that I have only 2 Active connections(lan and wireless), RAS Async Adapter is a preinstalled software adapter ,preinstalled software adapters does not have `MACAddress` except this one, so in your case you have 3 lan connections = 3 MACAddress + RAS MACAddress , If you want to choose between adapters types you may use `Net.NetworkInformation`

Comment: Open `Device Manager` >`View`> `Show hidden devices` >Expand `Network Adapters` ,you'll see all working adapters (software/hardware)

Comment: I´m still stuck In my code...

I choose one Of my LAN-Connections In a combobox. The problem Is, I don´t know how To link the LAN-Connection names With the "ManagementClass" (objMC) And the "ManagementObjectCollection" (objMOC). It´s realy neccesary To the it With the realnames Of the LAN-Connections, because I want To use it On differnt computers (all Of them has the same LAN-Connections)! Thats why I can´t To it by them mac-adresses.

Could you please help Me???

You see my code at the first post...

Comment: you change your post ,now this answer has no meaning !!! whatever ,I'll add another answer

Answer (score 1):

***A*** : Here is how to list ALL available adapters (Hardware w/without software)

```
Dim HardwareOnly As Boolean = True
    For Each LAN_Adapter As NetworkInterface In NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
        With LAN_Adapter
            If HardwareOnly = True Then 'According to MAC-Address
                If LAN_Adapter.GetPhysicalAddress.ToString <> "" Then
                    If LAN_Adapter.GetPhysicalAddress.ToString.StartsWith("00000000") = False Then
                        ComboBoxAdapterSelector.Items.Add(LAN_Adapter)
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                ComboBoxAdapterSelector.Items.Add(LAN_Adapter)
            End If
        End With
    Next
    ComboBoxAdapterSelector.DisplayMember = "Name"
```

> ***B*** : Now each item in `ComboBoxAdapterSelector` is refering to an
> adapter (NetworkInterface object)
>  'so using `If ComboBoxAdapterSelector.SelectedText = "Ethernet 2" Then`is not
> recommanded 
>  '`LAN_Adapter.Name = "Ethernet 2"` is not a static
> field 
>  the user can change it from the `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections`

```
If ComboBoxAdapterSelector.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim tmpAdapter As NetworkInterface = DirectCast(ComboBoxAdapterSelector.SelectedItem, NetworkInterface)

    Dim objMC As ManagementClass = New ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration")
    Dim objMOC As ManagementObjectCollection = objMC.GetInstances()
    For Each objMO As ManagementObject In objMOC
        'choose a static field to compare `objMO` with selected adapter => `tmpAdapter` <br>
        'for example `tmpAdapter.Description` `tmpAdapter.GetPhysicalAddress` `tmpAdapter.Id` etc
            If objMO.GetPropertyValue("SettingID") = tmpAdapter.Id Then
                'NOW you find the object that refers to what you select in ComboBoxAdapterSelector



                Dim objNewIP As ManagementBaseObject = Nothing
                Dim objSetIP As ManagementBaseObject = Nothing

                'your code



                Exit For
            End If
        Next objMO
    End If
```

Comment: I get an error for objMO.GetPropertyValue("SettingID") because option strict on... what can i do?

Comment: @vbnet_newer `objMO.GetPropertyValue("SettingID").ToString`